# Convert DateTime.Now to a valid Windows filename

Tags: c#, windows, filenames

I have had this issue quite a few times and have just been using a workaround but thought I would ask here in case there is an easier option. When I have a string from `DateTime.Now` and I then want to use this in a filename I can't because Windows doesn't allow the characters / and : in filenames, I have to go and replace them like this:

```
string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace('/', '_').Replace(':', '_');
```

Which seems a bit of a hassle, is there an easier way to do this? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a more logical iso8601-style pattern like `yyyyMMdd`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy")
```

Comment: be aware from the capital MM which is month and not mm which is minute .. very important !

Comment: This assumes the language does not use illegal filename characters in its dd, MM, or yyyy format. True for English. Not necessarily true for other languages.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Thanks, I have just tried using it and ran into that problem so came back to look at your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 53):

As written by Samich, but

```
// The following will produce 2011-10-24-13-10
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you don't trust me, try setting the culture to `new CultureInfo("ar-sa");` :-)

I'll add that, if you hate the world, this is the most precise thing to do:

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("D19");
```

There are 19 digits in `DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks`

If you hate the world even more:

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("X16");
```

There are 16 hex digits in `DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there was this much detail to DateTime, +1, thanks!

Comment: @BaliC I'll add that if you are in the "sport" of using `DateTime` to number your files, you should probably use `DateTime.UtcNow` so that you don't have problems around DST change time.

Answer (score 11):

Use a ToString pattern:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm") // will produce 2011-10-24-13-10
```

Comment: You'll have to use HH instead of hh or instead of 14 you'll get 02

Answer (score 3):

If you need the datetime to be more precise you can use:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("O").Replace(":", "_") //2016-09-21T13_14_01.3624587+02_00
```

or (if you need a little less)

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("s").Replace(":", "_") //2016-09-21T13_16_11
```

Both are valid file names and are sortable.

You can create an extensions method:

```
public static string ToFileName(this DateTime @this)
{
    return @this.ToString("O").Replace(":", "_");
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var saveZipToFile = "output_" + DateTime.Now.ToFileName() + ".zip";
```

The "s" format does not take time zones into account and thus the datetimes:

- 2014-11-15T18:32:17+00:00
- 2014-11-15T18:32:17+08:00

formatted using "s" are identical.

So if your datetimes represent dirrerent time zones I would recommend using "O" or using `DateTime.UtcNow`.

- The "O" format is compliant with ISO 8601, [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip)
- The "s" format is [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Sortable)

Answer (score 2):

You can use timestamp's long format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToBinary()
```